# Norm and Trace of the zeroes of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

"Consider the irreducible polynomial $g(x)=x^3+6x^2+3x+13 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Let $\alpha$ be any zero of $g$ and $ L =\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) $. Compute $N(\alpha-1)$ and $ \operatorname{Tr}(\alpha-1)$."

What I have so far:

We consider the map $A_{\alpha - 1} : L \to L$. This is given by $A_{\alpha - 1}(x) = (\alpha - 1)x$, where $x\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Now we consider how this acts on our basis $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$

We get $1\to-1+\alpha$, $\alpha\to0-\alpha+\alpha^2 $ and $\alpha^2\to-13-3\alpha-7\alpha^2$, giving us the transformation matrix of:

$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & -13\\1 & -1 & -3\\0 & 1 & -7\end{bmatrix}$

So $N(\alpha-1) = -1(7+3) - 13(1) = -23$ and $Tr(\alpha-1) = -1-1-7 =-9$

However, if I transform the polynomial by $x = x -1$, we get

$h(x)= g(x-1)= x^3+3x^2-6x+15$

which I believe suggests we have a norm of $15$ and a trace of $-6$

Where have I gone wrong? Is it just an arithmetic mistake somewhere?

Comment: Isn't $h(x)=g(x+1)$ (rather than $g(x-1)$? You want $\alpha-1$ to be the root of $h$.

Comment: I agree with Stinking Bishop, also you have written that the form of $h(x)$ suggests the trace is $-6$, but remember the trace is the negative of the coefficient of the $x^2$ term, not the $x$ term!